# group similar successive records that they are not separated by other deferent records - Mysql

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, how to group similar successive records that they are not separated by other deferent records

```
id | type |
1  | 1    |
2  | 1    |
3  | 1    |
4  | 5    |
5  | 1    |
6  | 8    |
7  | 1    |
8  | 3    |
9  | 3    |
10 | 3    |
```

the result should be like this :

```
id | type |
3  | 1    |
4  | 5    |
5  | 1    |
6  | 8    |
8  | 1    |
10 | 3    |
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "similar nearest, closest rows only".

Comment: Which is your question?  Timestamp has nothing to do with the first question.

Comment: closest, mean next and previous similar rows.
and if they are separated by other deferent row don't group it.

Comment: That should be 4,5,5 in the result, right?

Comment: strawberry the result should be ! 
3,4,5,6,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

  CREATE TABLE my_table
  (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  ,type INT NOT NULL
  ,x INT NOT NULL
  );

  INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
  (1,1,1),
  (2,1,1),
  (3,1,1),
  (4,5,5),
  (5,1,1),
  (6,8,8),
  (7,1,1),
  (8,1,1);

  SELECT MIN(c.id) id 
       , a.type
       , a.x
    FROM my_table a
    LEFT 
    JOIN my_table b 
      ON b.id + 1 = a.id 
     AND b.type = a.type
     AND b.x = a.x
    LEFT 
    JOIN my_table c 
      ON c.id >= a.id
     AND c.type = a.type
     AND c.x = a.x
    LEFT 
    JOIN my_table d 
      ON d.id - 1 = c.id 
     AND d.type = a.type
     AND d.x = a.x
   WHERE b.id IS NULL 
     AND c.id IS NOT NULL
     AND d.id IS NULL
   GROUP 
      BY a.id; 

  +------+------+---+
  |  id  | type | x |
  +------+------+---+
  |    3 |    1 | 1 |
  |    4 |    5 | 5 |
  |    5 |    1 | 1 |
  |    6 |    8 | 8 |
  |    8 |    1 | 1 |
  +------+------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a standard group by:

```
select count(*) id, type, `group`
from mytable
group by type, `group`
```

Note that you'll need to delimit the reserved word "group "

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather ill-formed.  I think the following might be close to what you want.  It identifies the groups based on consecutive `type` values by assigning a new `grp` column that identifies the consecutive groups.

```
select type, max(id) as maxid, count(*) as numingroup
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@type = type, @grp, if(@type := type, @grp + 1, @grp + 1))) as grp
      from my_table t cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @type := -1)x
      order by id
     ) t
group by grp, type;
```